# SDR - FM Radio station interference

Tags: rtl-sdr

I want to learn about software defined radio and how wireless transmission work in general.

So I started messing around with SDRSharp and a little antenna I bought.

I figured I would start looking at known frequencies like local radio stations. Some I can get to come in clear by messing with the digital noise reduction but this station (one of the strongest in my area) has a ton of background noise that I can't seem to filter.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The interfering harmonics are spaced at around 15.5 kHz. Do you have an old (CRT) TV set nearby? That may be the source, since TV line frequency is 15.625 Hz.

If not, look for other interfering electronics, such as compact fluorescent lights or other switched-mode power supplies (your own PC?).

Comment: lol I have my antenna above my desktop and in between 3 monitors... derp... Thanks!

Comment: Which version of SDRSharp did you use on which operationing system with what CPU and how much RAM? Is that just SDRSharp or need other 'add-in' software? Is install straight forward, as seen posting (may be due to old version) of some difficulty? Which hardware used? Many thanks